# How to resolve "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am receiving an error:

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)."

on the *nn_model.fit* line below.

Here my data.csv file contains columns: text (type object), attacment(type float), category(lable, type int).

```
# Split the dataframe into test and train data
def split_data(feat,label):
    # Train test split
    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
        feat, encode_labels(label), test_size=0.20, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
    data = {"train": {"X": x_train, "y": y_train},
            "test": {"X": x_val, "y": y_val}}
    return data

## label encoding for NN
def encode_labels(labels):
    # label processing
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(labels)
    classes = le.classes_
    encoded_labels = le.transform(labels)
    # convert integers to one-hot encoded w/Keras
    encoded_labels = utils.to_categorical(encoded_labels)
    return encoded_labels

def model():
        # CNN + LSTM model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Embedding(train_args["max_feature"], train_args["embed_size"], input_length=train_args["max_len"]))
        model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, padding='same', activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.1))  # regularize due to serious over-fitting
        model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, recurrent_dropout=0.02,return_sequences=True)))
        model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
        model.add(Dropout(0.1))
        model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(train_args["total_classes"], activation='softmax'))

        model.layers[0].trainable = True

        model.compile(optimizer='adam',  
                    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
        logger.info(model.summary())
        return model

# train the model, return the model
def train_model(data):    
    # Training
    logger.info("Starting training Neural Network")
    nn_model = model()
    history = nn_model.fit(data["train"]["X"], 
                data["train"]["y"], 
                batch_size=64, 
                epochs=10, 
                validation_data=(data["test"]["X"], data["test"]["y"]))
    logger.info("Finished training Neural Network")
    return nn_model

# Evaluate the metrics for the model
def get_model_metrics(model, data):
    preds = model.predict(data["test"]["X"])
    accuracy = accuracy_score(np.argmax(preds, axis=1), np.argmax(data["test"]["y"],axis=1))
    metrics = {"accuracy_score": accuracy}
    return metrics

def main():
    # Load the training data as dataframe
    data_dir = "data"
    data_file = os.path.join(data_dir, 'data.csv')
    train_df = pd.read_csv(data_file)
    label = train_df["category"]
    feat = train_df.drop(columns=['category'])

    data = split_data(feat,label)

    # Train the model
    model = train_model(data)

    # Log the metrics for the model
    metrics = get_model_metrics(model, data)
    for (k, v) in metrics.items():
        print(f"{k}: {v}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Most likely you have some integer format (created when reading the csv with pandas) which torch is not accepting. Maybe try to create a `torch.tensor` with [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html) before passing it to `model.fit()`?

Comment: I recently had the same problem and I vaguely remember solving it (if I am not confusing) by making type conversion to "Int64" note that not int64 as the capital "i" had something to do with numpy library or something? I tried googling the problem but couldnt find anything so I decided that maybe writing this was better than nothing I hope it will help

Comment: Thanks @CemKoçak, I've tried converting the offending columns to Int64, but got the same error. What's confusing me a bit is that it's always reporting `int` as the offending data type, even though it's supposedly int32/Int64.